# What is the alternative of AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping in Spring 4.3+ and 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have developed our framework based on Spring 4.2 since few years ago. Now we are planning to migrate Spring Framework to 5.3 but facing some problems. The major problem is that **AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping** not available anymore in Spring 5.3, but in our framework we create some classes extends it. I want to know what is the alternative in Spring 5.3 ? I guess there will be some new annotations else. Any ideas? please.

Spring Deprecated List: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.13.RELEASE/javadoc-api/deprecated-list.html

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping
as of 4.3, in favor of annotation-driven handler methods
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've created our BaseController extends **AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping** instead of **AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping**, it works perfectly.